# Which is the best moment to give a Pokemon a raise stat item?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

I'm playing Pokemon Red. When Pokemon reach level 100, the stat-up items (HP UP, Carbos, Calcium etc) don't work.

I want to know the utility of these items or the strategy to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Effort Values (EVs)

Pokemon have hidden stats called '[Effort Values](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Effort_values#Stat_experience)' (EVs) - one for each stat (HP, Attack, Defense, Speed, Special), with a value range of 0 - 65535 in Generation 1. These EVs are used to calculate the Pokemon's stats (the ones you can see on the Pokemon's summary screen). EVs can be gained by defeating other Pokemon in battle, or from using Vitamins (up to a point).

Any increase in EVs is not immediately factored in to a Pokemon's stats. A Pokemon's stats are only recalculated from three events:

- When the Pokemon levels up
- When the Pokemon evolves
- Using the [Box Trick](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Box_trick) (storing, then retrieving a Pokemon from Bill's PC)

#### When to apply Vitamins

You should give Pokemon raise-stat items - also known as [Vitamins](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Vitamin) - pretty much immediately. Do this before training them in battle, so you can take advantage of the maximum gain from the vitamins.

Each vitamin will apply 2560 Effort Values in the given stat, up to a limit of 25600. After you reach 25600 EVs in that stat, you'll need to train that Pokemon manually to increase the EVs beyond that limit.

Comment: Thanks. So vitamins really are not necessary because I can gain EVs simply by training, right?

Comment: @AlejandroTolcachier not necessary, but they can help by cutting down the time spent battling, and by allowing you to apply EVs without other things happening - like earning experience, levelling up, learning new moves, evolving